# Integer $k$ such that $k!$ has 99 zeros

Tags: number-theory

For how many positive integers $k$ does $k!$ has 99 zeros.

---

The question is not difficult,since if $k$ the first for $k!$ to have 99 zeros, then since $k+1,\cdots,k+4$ are not divided by 5, so the answer is 5.I just want to know what is the first to have 99 zeros. That goes to calculate the number of factors 5 in $k$

Comment: I'm not sure the question is easy unless you mean $k!$ *ending* in $99$ zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is $N= 400!$.  We can see this by noticing that the number of zeroes at the end of the expansion of $N$ is $$\left \lfloor{\frac{400}{5}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{400}{25}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{400}{125}}\right \rfloor = 80+16+3 = 99.$$

Of course, the number $399!$ has two fewer zeroes at the end of the expansion, since $400$ has divisors $5$ and $25$.